# Word frequency by date

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to store information from word frequency as follows

```
Date                My_List 
02/21/2020        [kitchen, chair] # just an example; I would like to keep only nouns
02/23/2020        [baby, cousin, secret ] # just an example
04/12/2019        [table, book, photocamera, apartment] #just an example
```

....

where on My_list there is the list of words with highest frequency.

My original dataset looks like:

```
 Date                My_List 
    02/21/2020        I bought for chairs for my kitchen
    02/21/2020        I look forward to help you cooking in your new kitchen.

    02/23/2020        Baby on board
    02/23/2020        I love you baby
    02/23/2020        When I was a baby, my cousin told me a secret...


    04/12/2019       Where did you buy this new photocamera?
    04/12/2019       I have no table in my new apartment. I should buy a new one.
    04/12/2019       How many book have you read this summer?


....
```

The expected table should contain the word frequency (tokenized) by date, i.e. considering texts within the same day to extract word frequency.
If you could give me any advice on how to group text in the same day to extract words more frequent, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have try `nltk`

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
s=df.set_index('Date').My_List.str.split(' ').explode()
s1=s.map(lambda x : wordnet.synsets(x))
s=s[s1.astype(bool)]
s1=s1[s1.astype(bool)]
s1=s1.map(lambda x : x[0].lexname().split('.')[0])
out=s[s1=='noun'].groupby(level=0).apply(pd.Series.mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method with `nltk`, extracting nouns that position tag `NN` or `NNS`. `NNS` is for Plural Nouns like `Chairs`.

```
import nltk
df['My_List'] = (df['My_List'].apply(lambda x: nltk.word_tokenize(x))
                 .apply(lambda x: nltk.pos_tag(x))
                 .apply(lambda x: [noun[0] for noun in filter(lambda x: x[1]=='NN' or x[1]=='NNS', x)]))
df = df.groupby('Date')['My_List'].sum().reset_index()
df['My_List'] = df['My_List'].map(pd.unique)
df

Out[26]: 
         Date                                        My_List
0  02/21/2020                              [chairs, kitchen]
1  02/23/2020                          [board, baby, cousin]
2  04/12/2019  [photocamera, table, apartment, book, summer]
```